# Iteration over a Pandas DataFrame to extract data

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame that contains hour intervals in the columns, and employee ID's in rows.
I want to iterate over each column(hourly interval) and extract it to a list ONLY if the column contains the number 1 (1 means they are available in that hour , 0 means they are not)

I've tried iterrows() and iteritems() and neither are giving me what I want to see from this DataFrame

[image]

Which is a new list called

available = [0800, 0900, 1000, 1100]

Which I can then extract the min and max values to create a schedule.

Apologies if this is somewhat vague Im pretty new to Python 3 and Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate

Suppose you have a dataframe like this

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
2   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
4   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
5   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0
7   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1
8   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
9   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1
```

You can just use this code to get the column names of all the columns where value is 1

```
df['available'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[row == 1].index.tolist(), axis=1)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   available
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   [5, 7, 8]
1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
2   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [0, 1, 2]
3   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]
4   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   [0, 2, 4, 6]
5   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [1, 2]
6   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   [0, 4, 5, 6, 7]
7   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
8   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   [2, 4, 5, 6]
9   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And if you want mix/max from this you can use

```
df['min_max'] = df['available'].apply(lambda x: (min(x), max(x)))

   available                  min_max
0   [5, 7, 8]                   (5, 8)
1   [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]    (0, 9)
2   [0, 1, 2]                   (0, 2)
3   [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]          (1, 9)
4   [0, 2, 4, 6]                (0, 6)
5   [1, 2]                      (1, 2)
6   [0, 4, 5, 6, 7]             (0, 7)
7   [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]       (1, 9)
8   [2, 4, 5, 6]                (2, 6)
9   [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]          (0, 9)
```

Comment: Ultimately, what I am trying to do is this.

Search through the list of Agent ID's who have availability to be scheduled in the 0800 hour, and add them to a list. Then do the same for each hour.

Then, with those lists I want to check if the agent ID has reached their max available hours for the week, then from that pool Schedule X agents in from hour 0800-0900. Ensuring to schedule enough from that list to meet the required number of agents for that hours expected volume.

I may be barking up the wrong tree, and there may be a better way to do this but I'l learning as I go!

Ess

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```py
available = df.columns[df.T.any(axis=1)].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not advisable to iterate over Pandas DataFrames unless they are small, as AFAIK this does not use vectorized functions and is thus slower.

Can you show the rest of your code?

Assuming only 0s and 1s are in the dataframe the following conditional selection should work (if I'm correctly interpreting what you want; it seems more likely that you want what
[Shubham Periwal posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67578429/8484932)):

```
filtered_df = df[df != 0]
lists = filtered_df.values.tolist()
```

Or in 1 line:

```
lists = df[df != 0].values.tolist()
```